# RewriteRule for multiple file names

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hyperlink

I was always using the next:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ page.php?name=category&type=$1 [L]
```

to rewrite my links. I used only ONE file name "page.php", and it worked.
Today, I want to add another file "project.php", and need another RewriteRule for it, and this is the full code I'm trying to use in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ page.php?name=category&type=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ project.php?category=$1&id=$4&type=$2&name=$3 [L]
```

But, it work only for the first path, and messes the second. Please, can anyone help to figure it out? I've tried to search for it for a while, but couldn't find a solution. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we get an example of the urls? Both the one for page.php and the one for project.php.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Jonathan. I cannot provide right now the live link, but when I try to GET the "category" from the second link:
project.php?category=$1&id=$4&type=$2&name=$3 (after the convertion of the link)
it gives me them all together, including the "id", "type", etc., with the slashes; e.g. one/two/three

Comment: Yes, I see that. I don't need the actual live link, I was just wondering what the link roughly looked like. The problem I can already tell you is that `(.*)` means "zero or more of any character". This would include the `/`. So all urls would match the `.*` making the first rule always true. Rewrite stops after that. You would be better off identifying what type of characters (numbers only, letters only, both...etc) are supposed to be in each group (between the parenthesis) and matching just that.

Comment: As Jonathan Kuhn said `(.*)` read all chars so put `project.php` rule as first and use at least `([^/]+)` in place of `(.*)` in that rule. `([^/]+)` read one or more chars except `/`.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn and furas, thank you very much! I changed (.*) to ([^/]+), and everything works fine now! I was so happy, so if you would be here, I'd hug you both :P
Sorry, I guess I'm too new here to rate your solutions. If somebody with a better reputation can do it instead of me, please do so - these folks helped me 100%.

Comment: @furas If you want to post your response as an answer so dnns can approve and close the question, that would be appreciated.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn So I post my response as an answer, thank you.

Comment: @dnns you can always mark answer as accepted (at least 10-15 min after question was asked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jonathan Kuhn said `(.*)` read all chars so put `project.php rule` as first and use at least `([^/]+)` in place of `(.*)` in that rule. `([^/]+)` read one or more chars except `/`.